# Wordpress Javascript Conflict; total js beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I have a javascript conflict on the homepage of this site: http://antimatterweblab.info/ws

There are two things that use javascript:

1. a date picker for the booking system, which is created by a plugin called 'Booking' and which is happy to use Wordpress' own javascript
2. A nav bar on the right of the screen that allows users to navigate to different sections of the homepage, which uses this code as well as Google's jQuery library:

   ```
   <!-- animate to section-->
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   function goToByScroll(id){
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
       }

       var t = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

       $(document).scroll(function(){
           if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
           {   
               $('#voice2').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #f4f5f8"});
               $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
               $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
               $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
               $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

The animation then works using this HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('house')"><div class="navcirc"></div></a>
```

...however, by using the Google library, the calendar doesn't work, and without the Google library, the goToByScroll function doesn't work.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED ALREADY**

1. Using a plugin to make Wordpress use Google's libraries instead made no difference - the scroll function still doesn't work unless the Google library has been called separately
2. Advice I have read elsewhere says to wrap the code in this:

   ```
   (function($){

   $(document).ready(function(){
    //document ready code here
   });

   })(jQuery);
   ```

...which I interpret as meaning to do this:

```
<!-- animate to section-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
        function goToByScroll(id){
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
        }

        var t = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
            {   
                $('#voice2').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #f4f5f8"});
                $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
                $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
                $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
                $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
            }
        });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This simply ends up disabling both the calendar and the scroller.

I have no idea what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: You have two versions of jQuery on the page.

Comment: why are you using this `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js` wordpress is already loaded the jquery.

Comment: Without the duplicate jquery from googleapi your first script should work just fine.

Comment: Afraid not. Not sure why, but the scroller ONLY works when I load the Google jQuery library, but that then stops the calendar working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jquery uses an alternate shortcut on your page.

Instead of the $ shortcut it is defined as jQuery.

Change your script like this and try it again:

```
    function goToByScroll(id){
            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
        }
```

Comment: That won't work. the `IIFE` handles that issue by passing in the `jQuery` reference.

Comment: Please explain. I don't have Wordpress and when I go to the mentioned site, paste the above function in the firebug console and call goToByScroll('experience') the side scrolls into place.

Comment: It did!

I was able to remove the Google library that was causing problems with the calendar and also the (function($){ ... });(jQuery); bit and now everything works perfectly!

Not exactly sure why, as as I say, js is not my thing but cheers @mainguy

Comment: Btw, I don't have enough rep points here to give points, but someone should give some to this gent - this bug had been ruining my life for while :)